# Python missing module v 2.7.3 and Windows 7: Installed fuzzywuzzy, imports in powershell, not in IDLE

Tags: python, windows, module, fuzzywuzzy

I'm betting there's a simple solution to this problem that I don't know, and from googling and stackoverflowing around it seems to have something to do with setting a path.

I have anaconda installed on my computer and it seems to use python 2.7.4.  I also have python 2.7.3 installed, which seems to be the version being used when I open up IDLE.  When I installed fuzzywuzzy using 'python setup.py install' it's installed in the anaconda folder and using python in powershell, the command 'from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz' works fine, but when doing the same thing in IDLE I get a missing module error.

Is there a way to reconcile the two versions of Python?  Can I get them to share packages, or delete one of the versions without ruining everything?

I tried doing this:

'''
Setting the PYTHONPATH / PYTHONHOME variables

Right click the Computer icon in the start menu, go to properties. On the left tab, go to Advanced system settings. In the window that comes up, go to the Advanced tab, then at the bottom click Environment Variables. Click in the list of user variables and start typing Python, and repeat for System variables, just to make certain that you don't have mis-set variables for PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME. Next, add new variables (I did in System rather than User, although it may work for User too): PYTHONPATH, set to C:\Python27\Lib. PYTHONHOME, set to C:\Python27.
'''

then reinstalled fuzzywuzzy, and it installed in the C:Python27 folder and works in IDLE, but now Kivy doesn't work!

Do I need to reinstall that too? Or is there a Path sharing fix?

Comment: Open `python.exe` in CMD. Then try it again.

Comment: You can also straight up add to python path: import sys, sys.path.insert(index,path). Get the sys.path from one of your pythons and insert/reconcile with the other. Or just get both sys.paths and add them to PYTHONPATH env. var. to make sure you get everything.

Comment: PYTHONPATH exists in system variables. autoexec.bat was used in 9x. XP has config files in WINDOWS directory. dont know there is it now. maybe registry?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap one of your conflict programs in CMD file. Like python-virtualenv.